# How add an image using Postfix After queue content filter?

Tags: postfix-mta

I want mailing using my smtp server and i have also configure postfix for this. But now i want add an image in every email using postfix after queue filter. I don't know how do it.

If anybody know how do it then please help me.

Dear clement thanks for help. I think mimedefang is perfect for my purpose. But i can't find any HOWTO which help me to configure it with postfix. If possible then please provide me more guide that how configure it postfix.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `mimedefang`? We use it as a `milter` with postfix to append text to every outgoing mails using `append_text_boilerplate`. `append_html_boilerplate` should work for you.More info about it [here](http://www.mickeyhill.com/mimedefang-howto/) Hope that helps.